# Dash localhost page to PDF

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

Good day I would like to save my dash graphs to a pdf and with this code:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import pdfkit


from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response

pdfdwnld = dash.Dash(__name__)
pdfdwnld.layout = html.Div(
                className="three columns",
                children=html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='right-top-graph',
                        figure={
                            'data': [{
                                'x': [1, 2, 3],
                                'y': [3, 1, 2],
                                'type': 'bar'
                            }],
                            'layout': {
                                'height': 400,
                                'margin': {'l': 10, 'b': 20, 't': 0, 'r': 0}
                            }
                        }
                    ),


                ])
            )

pdfdwnld.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
})

rendered = render_template('pdf_template.html',pdfdwnld)
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False)
response = make_response(pdf)
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdfdwnld.run_server(debug=True)
```

I am constantly getting below error:

> Documents\AllCode\Multiple Graphs> python .\pdfdwnld.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\MichaelMeuleman\OneDrive - Six Square Networks\Documents\AllCode\Multiple Graphs\pdfdwnld.py", line 42, in 
> rendered = render_template('pdf_template.html',pdfdwnld)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> TypeError: render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The `pdfdwnld.py` is my file name. I'm not 100% sure what to expect with this code. Where I believe that as soon as I run this in my terminal it should save my dash graphs as a pdf in a certain folder.

If I remove the file name in:

`rendered = render_template('pdf_template.html',pdfdwnld)`

I get this error:

> File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 145, in render_template
> app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
> raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
> the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
> with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.